# Handling ORACLE's XMLTYPE data in PHP

Tags: php, oracle, xmltype

We are implementing an online interface to connect to the ORACLE DB and allow users to do queries online. We came accross of XMLTYPE datatype in oracle and facing difficulties with it. To retrieve the DATA from a table which has XMLTYPE in it, a normal "select * from table_name" wouldn't work but we need to call that specific column with xmltype.getclobval(column_name). 
This would be a nice option if we handle queries from backend, but here we are allowing users to do query on their own. In this case users will just do a select * on that table but still I need to be able to fetch the data and display irrespective of whether it has XMLTYPE or not. Is there any way of doing it using native PHP Oracle drivers itself? Or do we need to write a plugin which handles this without notifying users that we are applying xmltype.getclobval() function in backend?

### Please help me in this aspect.

Thanks,
Lalith

Comment: I'm not familiar with PHP but perhaps a Schema VIEW can be an option too

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with PHP, but from OCI side, you have to handle XMLTYPE as a custom user defined type named "SYS.XMLTYPE". If you want use if as real XML you also need a library libxml.so. For some unknown reason this one is not part of Oracle Instant client.

Try to grep PHP driver sources for string "SYS.XMLTYPE".

Maybe you can simply use CLOB datatype as placeholder for XMLTYPE colum and Oracle will perform data conversion for you. The same way as if you used VARCHAR placeholder for numeric column.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your response. Lemme check and come back to you